# Issue with my histogram

Tags: plotting, histograms

i am sorry to come back to you all and yes i have checked the Manual but not found a solution for :-(

here is my call:

```
Histogram[{data}, {bspec}, LabelingFunction -> Above, 
 ImageSize -> {450, 250}]
```

The number of classes has been calculaed to 14 in my example (squarroot of the total amount of measurements).
bspec has been calculated by the number of classes (ratio to the difference from max to min) and in this example it is 2.5.

this all works perfectly and the the histogramm is right too.

But as you can see in the picture it is cutted on the right side
so that i just see 8+ classes -ok, there are just some data left, less
than 5 but it is cutted :-)

is there a way to solve it or a thing of mathematica?

thanks again

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the options `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding`.

Comment: Since this is already your third post, it is expected that you should format it yourself.  Please put the code in code blocks.  Click the ? button on the editing toolbar if you need help.

Comment: lovely...it works...i dont see a difference between Plotrange-> Full and ->All but it works..@Szabolcs: I will stop posting here. sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @MelanieGerster Have a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Full.html?q=Full) to see the difference between `Full`and `All`.

Comment: @Melanie I don't think anyone is suggesting you stop posting here.  At least I hope not.  Rather I believe Szabolcs is trying to guide you into using the site to your own benefit; questions without well-formatted code are often ignored or down-voted, so it is important to learn and use the formatting tools to have a good experience here.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PlotRange -> All` to avoid this.